# Defective Binary search in C

Tags: c, binary-search, insertion-sort

Currently, I have a program the implements insertion sort and then uses binary search to search it (an array of ints). I currently have a 1 off error it seems.

My insertion sort should sort in descending order. Right now, it seems as if the value stored in the last position is missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void insertionSort(int nums[], int size)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        key = nums[i];
        j = i - 1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        greater than key, to one position ahead
        of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && nums[j] > key)
        {
            nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        nums[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int binarySearch(int nums[], int size, int searchVal)
{
    int l = 0, r = size - 1;

    while (l <= r)
    {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        // Check if x is present at mid
        if (nums[m] == searchVal)
            return m;

        // If x greater, ignore left half
        if (nums[m] < searchVal)
            l = m + 1;

        // If x is smaller, ignore right half
        else
            r = m - 1;
    }

    // if we reach here, then element was
    // not present
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements (between 1 and 50) in the array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i, nums[n];
    printf("Enter %d positive integers: \n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
    }
    int x = 0;
    insertionSort(nums, n);
    printf("Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit: \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    do
    {
        int ind = binarySearch(nums, n, x);
        if (ind > 0)
        {
            printf("Found\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not Found\n");

        }
        printf("Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    } while (x != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Enter the number of elements (between 1 and 50) in the array:
9
Enter 9 positive integers:
7
4
10
49
6
12
32
17
Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit:
4
Not Found
Enter an positive integer -1 or to quit
12
Found
Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit:
5
Not Found
Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit:
49
Found
Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit:
-1
```

As you can see everything works but the first test where I test for the number 4. Does anyone know why I'm off by 1?

Comment: See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). One of the first steps here is to separate the sorting part and searching part and verify that the problem is where you think it is.

Comment: “Input 9 positive integers”, then there’s 8 given?

Comment: `if (ind > 0)` should be `if (ind >= 0)`.

Comment: `return m;` and `if (ind > 0)` will never find the element at index `0`...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertionSort (int nums[], int size)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        key = nums[i];
        j = i - 1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
           greater than key, to one position ahead
           of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && nums[j] > key) {
            nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        nums[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int binarySearch (int nums[], int size, int searchVal)
{
    int l = 0, r = size - 1;

    while (l <= r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        // Check if x is present at mid
        if (nums[m] == searchVal)
            return m;

        // If x greater, ignore left half
        if (nums[m] < searchVal)
            l = m + 1;

        // If x is smaller, ignore right half
        else
            r = m - 1;
    }

    // if we reach here, then element was
    // not present
    return -1;
}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    printf
        ("Enter the number of elements (between 1 and 50) in the array: \n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    int i, nums[n];
    printf ("Enter %d positive integers: \n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf ("%d", &nums[i]);
    }
    int x = 0;
    insertionSort (nums, n);
    printf ("Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit: \n");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    do {
        int ind = binarySearch (nums, n, x);
        if (ind >= 0) {
            printf ("Found\n");
        } else {
            printf ("Not Found\n");

        }
        printf ("Enter a positive integer or -1 to quit: \n");
        scanf ("%d", &x);
    } while (x != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Try this one 
just one error that is solve- if(ind>=0)

Answer (score 0):

While you have discovered that checking the `(ind > 0)` causes failure to find the elements at index `0` and `(ind >= 0)` provides a solution, let's look at a short test case that validates the `binarySearch()` finds all elements of your sorted array without the user having to continually enter or redirect information to your program.

Any time you are testing algorithms, provides a simple validation framework that tests all elements, numbers, etc. without a user input requirement. Take your '9' numbers for example. Simply including an initialized array and sorting and then looping over all values will validate whether the `binarySearch()` is performing as intended. (it will save you no end of grief in the process as well). A short code exercising your search over the complete array can be as simple as:

```
int main (void) {

    int nums[] = { 7, 4, 10, 49, 6, 12, 32, 17, 21 },
        n = sizeof nums / sizeof *nums;

    insertionSort (nums, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" %2d  (%s)\n", nums[i], 
                binarySearch (nums, n, nums[i]) >= 0 ? "found" : "not found");
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bsearchtest
  4  (found)
  6  (found)
  7  (found)
 10  (found)
 12  (found)
 17  (found)
 21  (found)
 32  (found)
 49  (found)
```

Each element is now listed as `"found"` or `"not found"` and the code exits on its own.